# Neo4j/Cypher Match only if predicate applies for all relationships

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I need to match nodes only when every relationship the node has fullfills a whereclause:

```
MATCH (o:Otherthing)
WHERE id(o) = 1
MATCH (unknown:Thing)
WHERE (unknown)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(:Thing)<-[:DEPENDS_ON*]-(:Thing)<-[:STARTED_WITH]-(o) 
RETURN unknown
```

Every matched "Thing" should only have relationships labeled with "DEPENDS_ON" and all of them should fullfill the condition.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you intending to use specific `Otherthing` nodes, or all `Otherthing` nodes?

Comment: I intend to use specific `Otherthing` nodes, thank you for the hint. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
MATCH (u:Thing)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(:Thing)<-[:DEPENDS_ON*]-(:Thing)<-[:STARTED_WITH]-(o)
WHERE ID(o) = 1
WITH u, COUNT(*) AS num
WHERE SIZE((u)--()) = num
RETURN u
```

The query uses an efficient degreeness check to get the total number of relationships for `u`, and compares that with the number of times `u` satisfied the `MATCH`. Also, since you are identifying `o` by its native ID (which I am assuming is always going to be the ID for an `Otherthing`), it is more efficient to not specify its label (to avoid a label verification operation).